# I cannot get this mute command very far

Tags: discord.js

I am currently working on a !mute command (or any other prefix) and since I am very new to JavaScript I am getting stuck. I have some of it down but can't get any father then that. I have a role set called "Muted". My code:

```
  bot.on('message', message =>{
      let args = message.content.substring(config.prefix.length).split(" ");

      switch (args[0]) {
          case 'mute':
              let person = message.guild.member(message.mentions.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[1]))
              if(!person) return message.reply("I could not find the person you are looking for... :thinking:")

      }
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setMute), muting a guild member is as simple as calling `member.setMute(true or false, reason)`, as the example points out:
`member.setMute(true, "It needed to be done")` mutes the targeted member with "It needed to be done" provided as a reason.